# What is the relationship between a UIPageViewController and a UIPageControl?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

So i'm building a simple app where I have three view controllers, and I want to be able to swipe between them (think, the way tinder flows through views from left to right).

The best way to do this appears to be using a UIPageViewController.

But I am getting confused with exactly how the UIPageControl gets involved in this process. I create a UIPageViewController, and can cycle through the three views, but how do I access the specific UIPageControl element that this process uses.

Or perhaps I've confused myself, and a UIPageControl element is not even used. Please help.

I should add, how do I access the UIPageControl element? Do I need to create it? Or is it there by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UIPageViewController` is a container view controller, that is a view controller that can contain other view controllers.  These other view controllers are the pages that you want to display, while a `UIPageControl` is a user interface element that the user can interact with.

In order to support a `UIPageViewController` you need to implement a the `UITableViewDatasource` protocol somewhere in your code.  This protocol is used to supply the view controller for each page.  The `UIPageViewController` implements a swipe gesture recogniser and the transition between each page.

If you implement the `presentationCountForPageViewController` and `presentationIndexForPageViewController` data source methods, then the `UIPageViewController` will display a `UIPageControl` (dots) at the top of the screen and also handle the user interacting with this control.

When you use a `UIPageControl` you can place it anywhere on your view, just like any other control, you need to set properties that indicate the number of pages & the selected page, and you need to implement an action handler to handle user interaction with the control; what you do with the user action is up to you.

Finally, here are a couple of tutorials that demonstrate:

- [Use of the UIPageViewController](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/)
- [Adding a UIPageControl to a UIPageViewController](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/11/move-uipageviewcontroller-dots/)